# The event Calendar query future and not ended events

Tags: wordpress

I would like to show coming events and also not ended ones.
At this time it shows future events and not events which began earlier and are not ended.

Here is my Query:

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$events_args = array(
 'showposts' => '5',
 'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
 'post_status'      => 'publish',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
  'key' => '_EventStartDate',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '>=',
  ),
  array(
  'key' => '_EventEndDate',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '>=',
  )
 )
);
?>
```

Any help appreciated.
Best.
Pierre

Comment: Hello everybody,
any ideas or tips ?
Best

Answer (score 1):

Ok not needed to be complicated with ‘relation’ => ‘AND’.

This one works like a charm.

Resolved ;-).

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$events_args = array(
 'showposts' => '5',
 'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
  'key' => '_EventEndDate',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '>=',
  )
 )
);
?>
```